# How can I make a full-width section slide-in for mobile browsers?

Tags: jquery, css

Example structure:

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

I want .main to slide off to the left as .slider slides in from the right.

Comment: please post full code or example. what you want exactly?

Comment: I really like how Amazon does their filter controls on most mobile devices: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s/ref=is_s?k=books

(Works great in chrome's Nexus 4 mobile device mode https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#enable-device-mode )

Comment: Have you written any code currently? Or attempted anything? Your links don't seem to be too helpful identify what your trying to do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I did:

```
$("#mobile-filter").on('click', function()  {
    var $refine = $('#slider').clone();
    var $main = $("#main");
    $main.before($refine);
    var $placed_refine = $main.siblings('#slider');
    var page_width = $('body').width();
    $main.css('position', 'relative');
    // Animate out to the left
    $main.animate({left: -(page_width) + 'px'}, 500);
    $placed_refine.css({'position': 'fixed', 'right': '-200px'});
    var refine_width = $placed_refine.outerWidth();
    var refine_placement = (page_width - refine_width) + 'px';
    // Animate in from the right
    $placed_refine.animate({right: refine_placement}, 500, function(){
        // Make it scrollable
        $placed_refine.css({'position': 'absolute', 'right': 'initial'});
    });
    // Animate it back
    $(".results-back").on('click', function() {
        $placed_refine.css({'position': 'fixed', 'right': refine_placement});
        $placed_refine.animate({right: '-200px'}, 500, function(){
            $placed_refine.remove();
        });
        $main.animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
    });
});
```